# Error launching a docker-compose command on Centos

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing development on a Mac and deploying to a Centos 7.4 install. When running on the latest docker/docker-compose I'm getting a weird error on one of them after upgrading.

On the Mac the command works as intended. The setup.sh script executes. On Centos it chokes:

`backend_1  | python: can't open file 'sh': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

The command successfully launched in both environments previously.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes_from:
        - data
    depends_on:
        - data

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    build: nginx/.
    restart: always
    volumes: 
        - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        - ./nginx/ssl-bundle.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/site_com/ssl_bundle.crt
        - ./nginx/site_com.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt
        - ./nginx/site.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/site_com/site.key
        - ./nginx/site.key:/etc/ssl/private/site.key
        - static:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
    depends_on:
        - backend
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - backend:backend


  backend:
    image: colstrom/python:legacy
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    command: sh docker/setup.sh
    volumes:
        - /usr/src/app
        - static:/code/site/static
    depends_on:
        - db
    expose:
        - "8000"


  data:
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    static:
```

Mac

- docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
- Docker version
  18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

Centos

- docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
- Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and the `setup.sh` script?  This fragment of a Compose file on its own isn't a [mcve].  To me the `volumes: [/usr/src/app]` line looks strange (and will cause Docker to overwrite whatever's in the image with an implicit volume, which could be a source of differences).

Comment: @DavidMaze updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is likely running `python` as its entry point, so having `command: sh docker/setup.sh` could result in the container trying to run `python sh docker/setup.sh`, which isn't what you want. Try replacing your `command:` directive in the backend declaration with this:

```
entrypoint: [ /bin/sh, docker/setup.sh ]
```